# Same databases on different servers

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, web-config

Maybe the title of this question isn't very helpful or might be off topic...
I have created mySQL database which has the same name and the same table as the mySQL database I was given by the server where I'm hosting my app.
In my Asp.net project I use my database and use Entity Framework.

So with two different tables that have the same names and same tables it's just the connString(or is it?), my question would be, how do I let my website know that he should use the database on this server?

I asked the support of my host for help their reply was:"Sorry we have no experience in Your framework"!!

So this is where I have to turn for help.

**EDIT:**

```
 <add name="tuuletfi_tidmediacafeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=aleksalukic;database=tuuletfi_tidmediacafe&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

this is my entire connection string for the VS2015
Also I access the server DB with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Indeed on your webconfig constring you should define the instance you want to connect (either the local or the remote)

Comment: well i set the server=myRemoteServer...but it's giving me the error, or the silent treatment which ever you like to call it more..

Comment: You must update both server name and corresponding port of the database of connection string in your web config.

Comment: where do I change the port? there is no such number in web.config

Comment: Although, one should not pastes the actual userId and Password, I hope the password is not the real one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ConnectionString on your Web.Config:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: change it there too? or do you mean where ever my connString is set?

Comment: You should always use the connection string that is set on your web config. If you have it set in another place, change it there too or point it to the web  config one

Comment: I don't have the app.config file...just web.config

Comment: I did change it there, still nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

Has you try with a connection string like this

UPDATE this is extract from my webconfig pls check MYSQL driver version compliant with yours

```
  <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />

<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
```

```
<add name="mysql" connectionString="server=x.x.x.x;User Id=root;password=123456;database=appdb;pooling=false;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

... before and of configuration

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Change db/usr/pass with your data

Comment: @MicroDev I update with all you need in yuor config. In my case I use Mysql and MSSQL if you don't need MSSQL pls remove it

Comment: Do i insert all of this into my web.config file and then upload it trough fileZilla?

Comment: yes, you need to change your web.config and upload.

Comment: nope, still doesn't work, my case is very specific, only someone who would use teamViewer and see the problem by himself would be able to help me...tnx for the effort though!

Comment: @MicroDev where is hosted your site?

Comment: mysql2.sigmatic.fi that is the name of the server and it uses phpMyAdmin

Comment: @MicroDev mysql is hosted on sigmatic.fi and .NET apps where is? or are you using VPS at sigmatic.fi?

Comment: My website is on my PC and on hosting server grid1.sigmatic.fi, I transfer it there via FTP

Comment: sorry but sigmatic don't have an english version and I use google translator but I don't find any information about hosting .NET application. Are u sure that you can publish this kind of apps? So, you can create a free account on azure and try to publish you app on it. App on azure db on sigmatic.